# Mypy and second-order decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to implement a second-order decorator that injects a dynamic variable as first argument of the decorated function.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
U = TypeVar('U')
P = ParamSpec('P')


def foo(some_arg: U) -> Callable[
    [Callable[Concatenate[U, P], T]],
    Callable[P, T],
]:
    def decorator(fn: Callable[Concatenate[U, P], T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
            return fn(some_arg, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

When running mypy, I got the following error:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (
    got "Callable[[Arg(Callable[[U, **P], T], 'fn')], Callable[P, T]]",
    expected "Callable[[Callable[[U, **P], T]], Callable[P, T]]")  [return-value]
```

I don't understand what I got wrong.
I couldn't found any information about the `Arg` element that Mypy says it got (couldn't find `typing.Arg` in mypy documentation).

How should I declare the return value of my decorator factory ?
How should I interpret this error output from mypy ? Any source from the doc I might have missed ?

Comment: It's a bug. Apparently it's fixed on master (1.5.1 errors, master works, see [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&gist=c8aa13f5abf66beb76b57a246a90b7bc)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @STerliakov already mentioned, this is most likely a bug.
But as far as I see the confusion mypy runs into is that you've specified to return a callable with one unnamed argument while you return a function whose first argument is called `fn`. This isn't an error as the you may pass optionally named arguments positionally as well (therefore it's a bug).

If you're currently unable to upgrade mypy, making `fn` a must-be positional argument (by adding `/` in the signature), may fix your problem:

```
    def decorator(fn: Callable[Concatenate[U, P], T], /) -> Callable[P, T]:
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
            return fn(some_arg, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Comment: Indeed: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.5.1&python=3.11&gist=f78eaabc45c80696f4ff8774432f1780
Seems fixed in mypy 1.6. Thanks.